# Find all Divs after being created with JQuery on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find all divs that have been created from my click event and split them into another div (.wrapAll) on a count of 3. I can't seem to get anything back when i console.log the vars length. I know this works when I do that same process on the html thats been statically typed. Below is my code and thank you fo the thoughts!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // load default twitch channels
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?', function(data) {
     //console.log(data);
  });
  // Bind 'Enter' to click event
  $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#search').trigger('click');
    }
  });
  // manually search for games
  $('#search').on("click", function() {
    // clear previous results and get search term
    $('#results').html('');
    search = $('#searchTerm').val();
    // begin API call
    $.getJSON( "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=" + search + "", function(data2) {
      // console.log(data2.streams.length);
      data2.streams.forEach(function(entry) {
        //console.log(entry._links);
        var streamURL = entry.channel.url;   
        url = entry.preview.medium;
        $('#results').append('<div class="searchResults"><a href="' + streamURL + '" target="_blank"><img class="games" src=' + url + '/><p id="title"> Game: ' + entry.channel.game + '<br> Viewers: ' + entry.viewers +'<br> Is Mature: ' + entry.channel.mature + '<br> Status: ' + entry.channel.status + ' </p></a></div><hr>');
      });
    });
    // Get 3 divs and slice into one div to style ** problem child **
    var a = $('div[id^=searchResu]').find('div');
    console.log(a.length);
    for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=3 ) {
      a.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="slide"></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. You can't look for the elements until they have been inserted

Comment: So do i need to create a function that does that after my click event is done?

Comment: No...right after you insert them...in `$.getJSON` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rzEecqOT2KfpcAsmofBH?p=preview) here. I believe this does what your looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            function appendHtmlContent(resultHtmlContent) {
                resultHtmlContent = '<div class="slide">' + resultHtmlContent + '</div>';
                $('#results').append(resultHtmlContent);
            }

            function processSvcResponse(data2) {
                var count = 0,
                        searchResultContents = '',
                        $div = $("<div>", { class: "searchResults"});
                data2.streams.forEach(function(entry) {
                    var streamURL = entry.channel.url;
                    url = entry.preview.medium;

                    searchResultContents += '<div class="searchResults"><a href="' + streamURL 
                        + '" target="_blank"><img class="games" src=' + url + '/><p id="title"> Game: ' + entry.channel.game 
                        + '<br> Viewers: ' + entry.viewers + '<br> Is Mature: ' + entry.channel.mature 
                        + '<br> Status: ' + entry.channel.status + ' </p></a></div><hr>';

                    count++;

                    if(count === 3) {
                        appendHtmlContent(searchResultContents);
                        searchResultContents = '';
                        count =  0;
                    }
                });

                // more results that have not been appended?
                if(searchResultContents) {
                    appendHtmlContent(searchResultContents);
                }

            }

            // load default twitch channels
            $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?', function(data) {});

            // Bind 'Enter' to click event
            $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $('#search').trigger('click');
                }
            });

            // manually search for games
            $('#search').on("click", function() {
                // clear previous results and get search term
                $('#results').html('');
                search = $('#searchTerm').val();
                // begin API call
                $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=" + search, processSvcResponse);

            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="searchTerm" type="text" />
    <button id="search" type="button">Search</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

If I understand correctly you are wanting to iterate over the results and for every third one wrap it inside a div with class "slider". As mentioned in the comments by @charlietfl in order to query newly created DOM elements using jQuery you have to query them *after* they are created. In the call to jQuery.getJSON the second argument accepts a callback function. The signature is jQuery.getJSON(url, someCallbackFunction). In order to make your code a bit more readable I moved "function(data2)" up and named it processSvcResponse. Inside processSvcResponse I build up an HTML string from the results and track how many results are processed by using a counter variable. Once the counter reaches 3 I append the contents to the results div and reset the counter. This solution does not "find" the divs and slice/wrapAll as you were intending to do originally, however, I believe this still accomplishes your goal.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! This is exctly what i was looking for. Sorry for the delayed response an inability to upvote. But, yes, this is perfect, thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. I believe you can mark as answer since you are the OP of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl said, you'll need to place the code that wraps your divs in the callback for getJSON. Your click event listener would look something like this then:

```
  $('#search').on("click", function() {
    // clear previous results and get search term
    $('#results').html('');
    search = $('#searchTerm').val();
    // begin API call
    $.getJSON( "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=" + search + "", function(data2) {
      // console.log(data2.streams.length);
      data2.streams.forEach(function(entry) {
        //console.log(entry._links);
        var streamURL = entry.channel.url;   
        url = entry.preview.medium;
        $('#results').append('<div class="searchResults"><a href="' + streamURL + '" target="_blank"><img class="games" src=' + url + '/><p id="title"> Game: ' + entry.channel.game + '<br> Viewers: ' + entry.viewers +'<br> Is Mature: ' + entry.channel.mature + '<br> Status: ' + entry.channel.status + ' </p></a></div><hr>');
      });
      // Get 3 divs and slice into one div to style ** problem child **
      var a = $('div[id^=searchResu]').find('div');
      console.log(a.length);
      for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=3 ) {
        a.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="slide"></div>');
      }
    });
  });
```